# Why doesn't getByRole get an element with a name (but it does with aria-label)?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, react-testing-library

What I'm trying is to get a `<button/>` with `getByRole` for unit testing. Here's a simplified example:

```
<Button
  classes={myCustomClass}
  name={'day'}
>
  <ViewDayOutlinedIcon /> {/** <- This is a Material UI icon */}
</Button>

// There are similar other buttons with different values in "name" attribute
```

The test case looks like...

```
render(<Component/>);
const dayButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'day' });

// fire events with dayButton and expect something
```

The console says `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "button" and name "day"`, and shows the following

```
Here are the accessible roles:

  button:

    Name "":
    <button
      class="MuiButtonBase-root makeStyles-iconButtonRoot-19 MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-78trlr-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root"
      name="day"
      tabindex="0"
      type="button"
    />
```

If I replace `name={'day'}` with `aria-label={'day'}` in the component, the button can be found by `screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'day' })`.

Why does it happen? `getByRole` is supposed to find an element by a name attribute and a wigdet role (`button`, `chekckbox`, `link`, etc), right? I can't find the answer from [RTL's doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[W3C Accessible Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name)**:

> The accessible name is the name of a user interface element. Each platform accessibility API provides the accessible name property. The value of the accessible name may be derived from a visible (e.g., the visible text on a button) or invisible (e.g., the text alternative that describes an icon) property of the user interface element.

> A simple use for the accessible name property may be illustrated by an "OK" button. The text "OK" is the accessible name.

MDN [basic buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role#basic_buttons):

> Buttons should always have an accessible name. For most buttons, this name will be the same as the text inside the button, between the opening and closing tags.

So the text "Day" is the accessible name for your case **NOT** the `name` attribute of the button HTML element.

Try:

```js
screen.getByRole('button', { name: /day/i });
```

The `name` option accepts a [`TextMatch`](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#textmatch), it can be a string or regex.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. In my case, `screen.getByRole('button', { name: /day/i });` didn't work simply because my example snippet was wrong. The button component had an icon component, not a text. Still, your advice is totally spot on, so I marked it as the solution